# can't create an index with mongock on a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongock

Each time I try to create an index on a collection with mongock I have this error:

Command createIndexes does not support this transaction's { readConcern: { level: "majority", provenance: "clientSupplied" } } :: caused by :: read concern not supported

my code :

```
@ChangeUnit(id = "init-index", order = "3", author = "mongock", transactional = false)
@Component
open class InitIndex(
    @NonLockGuarded
    private val ordersMongoTemplate: MongoTemplate,
    @NonLockGuarded
    private val env: Environment,
    @NonLockGuarded
    private val mongoOperations: MongoOperations,
) {
    @Execution
    open fun execution() {
        val expirationPeriod = "P6666D"

        mongoOperations
            .indexOps("myCollection")
            .ensureIndex(
                Index("myField", Sort.Direction.ASC)
                    .named("myField")
                    .expire(Duration.parse(expirationPeriod))
                    .background()
            )

    }
```

any idea what it is?

Comment: When using majority read concern the node will return only values that are known to have reached a majority of the replica set rather than the most recently written.  It is not possible to build an index on just the majority committed values.  Try explicitly setting the read concern to "local" or "available" for that operation.

Answer (score 0):

Mongock provides `@BeforeExecution` annotation for those operations that need to be executed without transaction scope. You can add an additional method to your ChangeUnit for that purpose.

Please take a look to the documentation and examples in the following [link](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/migration/index.html#changeunit-methods).